# Unity3D - Why is refactoring my script in an easy copied way not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, refactoring, pass-by-reference

I have an Object that gets replaced by thousands of little cubes at once, which then begin moving one after another after initialization.

I have code that works, but when I try to refactor it to clean it up, it stops working. The cubes dont move. This happens when I try to separate the Variable Initialisation and the Movement Initialisation.

*So this is my original code segment and it works:*

```cs
public class WallCreation : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform wallSegmentPrefab;
    GameObject oldWall;
    Vector3 oldWallSize;
    int oldWallsizeX;
    int oldWallsizeY;
    int oldWallsizeZ;
    Vector3 oldWallPosition;
    Vector3 oldWallCornerPosition;
    Transform newWall;
    Transform parentWallSegment;
    Transform[ , , ] wallSegments;
    int[] indizes;

    void Start () { 
        indizes= new int[3];
    }

    public void newWallScript(){
        initializeNewWall ("zWall++");
        StartCoroutine (waitForMovement ());
    }

    void initializeNewWall(string replaceWall)
    {
        oldWall = GameObject.Find(replaceWall);
        oldWallSize = oldWall.transform.localScale;
        oldWallPosition = oldWall.transform.localPosition;
        oldWallsizeX=(int) oldWallSize.x;
        oldWallsizeY=(int) oldWallSize.y;
        oldWallsizeZ=(int) oldWallSize.z;
        oldWallCornerPosition = oldWallPosition - oldWallSize / 2 + wallSegmentPrefab.localScale / 2;

        wallSegments = new Transform[oldWallsizeX , oldWallsizeY , oldWallsizeZ];

        for (int x = 0; x < oldWallsizeX; x++)
        {           
            for (int y = 0; y < oldWallsizeY; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < oldWallsizeZ; z++)
                {
                    newWall = Instantiate(wallSegmentPrefab);

                    GameObject _wallSegment = newWall.gameObject;
                    _wallSegment.AddComponent<WallMovement> ();
                    wallSegments[x,y,z] = newWall;
                }
            }
        }
        oldWall.SetActive(false);
    }

    void newWallMovement()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < oldWallsizeX-1; x++)
        {
            indizes [0] = x;                   
            for (int y = 0; y < oldWallsizeY; y++) 
            {
                indizes [1] = y;
                for (int z = 0; z < oldWallsizeZ; z++) {
                    indizes[2] = z;

                    newWall = wallSegments[x,y,z];
                    GameObject _wallSegment = newWall.gameObject;
                    WallMovement _WallMovement = _wallSegment.GetComponent<WallMovement> ();
                    _WallMovement.indizes = indizes;

                    _WallMovement.initializeMovement ();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator waitForMovement()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        newWallMovement();
    }
}
```

*This is my improved code that does not work and (...) stays the same:*

```cs
public class WallCreation : MonoBehaviour {

    (...) 

    void Start () { 
        indizes= new int[3];
    }

    public void newWallScript(){
        initializeNewWall ("zWall++");
        StartCoroutine (waitForMovement ());
        StartCoroutine (waitForMoving());
    }

    void initializeNewWall(string replaceWall)
    {
        (...)
    }

    void newWallMovement()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < oldWallsizeX-1; x++)
        {
            indizes [0] = x;                   
            for (int y = 0; y < oldWallsizeY; y++) 
            {
                indizes [1] = y;
                for (int z = 0; z < oldWallsizeZ; z++) {
                    indizes[2] = z;

                    newWall = wallSegments[x,y,z];
                    GameObject _wallSegment = newWall.gameObject;
                    WallMovement _WallMovement = _wallSegment.GetComponent<WallMovement> ();
                    _WallMovement.indizes = indizes;

                    //this is cut out and put into the wallMoving() void
                    //_WallMovement.initializeMovement ();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    void wallMoving(){
        for (int x = 1; x < oldWallsizeX-1; x++)
        {
            //indizes [0] = x; //only with this enabled it works for some reason, otherwise it doesn't                    
            for (int y = 0; y < oldWallsizeY; y++) 
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < oldWallsizeZ; z++) {
                    newWall = wallSegments[x,y,z];
                    GameObject _wallSegment = newWall.gameObject;
                    WallMovement _WallMovement = _wallSegment.GetComponent<WallMovement> ();

                    //same code but without giving the list indizes[] to the script/gameObject
                    _WallMovement.initializeMovement ();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    IEnumerator waitForMovement()
    {
        (...)
    }
    IEnumerator waitForMoving()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        wallMoving();
    }
}
```

When I separate this line 
`_WallMovement.initializeMovement ();`
to another function, the game continues to work, but the wall doesnt move this time. The Indizes seem to not be initialized anymore. This however does not result in an error in the console.

!!Mistake found!!!
I pass the indize by reference and not by value to the wallscripts. Therefore when I change the indizes in the main script they all get changed in every wall script. 
So when I call the public functions of the wall later, they all use the same indizes and therefore are not effected by my "Initialization" in the first place.
Otherwise if I change the indizes values before I call the wall function it works again, because the script now uses the correct corresponding values.
Thanks go out to https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/
for looking over this really stupid mistake and tellig me what no one else here could.

## Here is some additional code from my script:

This is what happens in the WallMovement script, that got attached to every cube of the wall:

```cs
public class WallMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public int[] indizes ;
    int indize;

    int modulo;

    public void initializeMovement()
    {
        modulo = indizes [0] % 2; 
        if (modulo>0) 
        {           
            //do something
        } 
        else 
        {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question should be merged with, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336738/unity-refactored-crumbling-wall-script-stops-working, as it is a duplicate.